# c++ Forward declaration, translation unit, linking

Tags: linker, external, declaration, forward

[On this site](http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/common_341_342/notes/storage_linkage.html)
I read:

```
class MyClass;
```

> simply states that "there is such a class" and its full definition will be "coming later" (either in the current file, at compile time, or from some other file at link time)

I'm not sure If I understand this process at the link time. I wrote the code below that should demonstrates it. Please if I'm wrong, correct me. I'm not sure how forward declaration at link time works.

```
//first.h
-----------
class Second;

class First{
public:
    Second* ptr;
    First();
};

//first.cpp
-----------
#include "first.h"
extern Second second;
First::First(){ptr = &second;}

//second.h
----------
class Second{
public:
    Second(){};
};

//main.cpp
----------
#include "second.h"
Second second;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

This code is compiled. If the line Second second; is commented, linker throws: undefined reference to 'second'.
Some comment putting together 1) forward declaration 2) compilation unit 3) linking might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the documentation you've read has mislead you by its laxity:

```
class MyClass;
```

doesn't exactly mean *there is such a class*, because the
only way to make a class *exist* is to define it, and a declaration is
not a definition. The declaration would be better read as: *Assume there is such a class*.

And it *doesn't* mean that full definition of the class will, or will not, be coming later. It's
full definition might need to come later for successful compilation. Or
not. And if the full class definition does need to come later,
it will need to come *for successful compilation*; therefore at compiletime, not linktime.

The undefined reference linkage error that you are able to provoke
by commenting out `Second second;` in `main.cpp` is simply a
plain old undefined reference error such as you'll always get
be trying to link a program in which a variable declared `extern`
is referenced somewhere and defined nowhere. It has no essential
connection with the `extern` variable being of class type - rather
than, say, `int` - or with the business of forward class declaration.

Forward declaration of classes is only ever *necessary* to preempt
a deadlock when the compiler attempts to parse the definitions of
of two classes that are interdependent and is unable to complete
either class definition before it completes the other one.

An elementary example: I naively write two classes `first` and `second`, of which
each has a method that uses an object of the other class and calls
one of *its* methods:

**first.h**

```
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "second.h"

struct first {

    std::string get_type() const {
        return "First";
    }
    void use_a_second(second const & second) const {
        std::cout << second.get_type() << std::endl;
    }

};

#endif
```

**second.h**

```
#ifndef SECOND_H
#define SECOND_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "first.h"

struct second {

    std::string get_type() const {
        return "First";
    }
    void use_a_first(first const & first) const {
        std::cout << first.get_type() << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"

int main()
{
    first f;
    second s;
    f.use_a_second(s);
    s.use_a_first(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Try to compile `main.cpp`:

```
$ g++ -c -o main.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp 
In file included from first.h:6:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
second.h:13:19: error: ‘first’ has not been declared
  void use_a_first(first const & first) const {
                   ^~~~~
second.h: In member function ‘void second::use_a_first(const int&) const’:
second.h:14:22: error: request for member ‘get_type’ in ‘first’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   std::cout << first.get_type() << std::endl;
                      ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
  second.use_a_first(first);
```

The compiler is stymied, because `first.h` includes `second.h`, and
*vice versa*, so it can't get the definition of `first` before it
gets the definition of `second`, which requires the definition of `first`...
 and *vice versa*.

A forward *declaration* of each class before the *definition* of the
other one, and a correspending refactoring of each class into
a *definition* and an *implementation*, gets us out of this deadly embrace:

**first.h (fixed)**

```
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H

#include <string>

struct second; // Declaration

struct first{
    std::string get_type() const {
        return "first";
    }
    void use_a_second(second const & second) const;
};

#endif
```

**second.h (fixed)**

```
#ifndef SECOND_H
#define SECOND_H

#include <string>

struct first; //Declaration

struct second{
    std::string get_type() const {
        return "second";
    }
    void use_a_first(first const & first) const;

};

#endif
```

**first.cpp (new)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"

void first::use_a_second(second const & second) const {
    std::cout << second.get_type() << std::endl;
}
```

**second.cpp (new)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"

void second::use_a_first(first const & first) const {
    std::cout << first.get_type() << std::endl;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ -c -o first.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic first.cpp
$ g++ -c -o second.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic second.cpp
$ g++ -c -o main.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
```

Link:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o first.o second.o
```

Run:

```
$ ./prog
second
first
```

This is the only scenario for which forward class declaration is
*needed*. It *can* be used in wider circumstances: see [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/1362568). The need is only every a need
for successful *compilation*, not linkage. Linkage can't be attempted till
compilation succeeds.

The documentation snippet is also misleadingly imprecise in the use of the word *definition*. The
definition of a class means one thing in the context of compilation and that's
what it *should* mean in the interest of clarity. It means something else, loosely,
in the context of linkage and it *shouldn't* mean that in the interest of clarity.
In the context of linkage, we'd better only talk about the *implementation* of
a class - and even that is a notion that begs for qualification.

As far as the compiler is concerned a class is *defined* if it gets from
the start to the end of:

```
class foo ... {
    ...
};
```

without error, and then the class definition is the contents of that span. A complete definition
does not mean, of course, that a class has a complete *implementation*. It
only has that if, in addition to a complete definition, all the methods and 
static members that are *declared* in its definition are also themselves *defined* somewhere, either
in-line within the class definition; out-of-line in a containing translation
unit, or in other translation units (possibly compiled in external
libraries) with which the compiled containing translation unit gets linked.
If any of those member definitions are not provided in one of those ways
come link-time, an unresolved reference linkage error will result. That
is a deficit of the class *implementation*.

The linker's idea of *definition* is different from the C++
compiler's and more elementary. From the linker's point of view, 
a C++ class doesn't actually exist. For the linker, the class implementation is boiled down, by the compiler, 
to a bunch of symbols and symbol definitions not essentially different from what it gets 
from any language compiler, whether or not the language deals in *classes* at all.
What matters to the linker, for success, is that all the symbols that are referenced in the output binary
have *definitions* either in the same binary or in dynamic libraries requested
in the linkage. A symbol (broadly) can identify some executable code or some data. 
For a code symbol, *definition* means *implementation* to the linker: the definition is the represented code, if any.
For a data symbol, *definition* means *value* to the linker: it means the represented data, if any.

So when the snippet says:

> .. and its full definition will be "coming later" (either in the current file, at compile time, or from some other file at link time)

this needs to picked apart.

The full definition of class `foo` must be come later in the *compilation* of
a translation unit, before type `foo` is required as the type of anything *else*,
specifically, the type of a base class, or function/method argument, or object<sup>1</sup>.
If this requirement is not satisfied a *compile* error will result:-

- A class cannot be fully defined if any base class is not fully defined.
- A function or method cannot be fully defined if it has an argument of a type
  that is not fully defined.
- An object cannot exist of any type that is not fully defined.

If `foo` is *never* required later to be the type of a base class, argument or object,
then the definition of class `foo` need never follow the declaration.

The full *implementation* of class `foo` *may or may not* be required, or
provided, by the linkage. Since the linker doesn't know about classes,
it doesn't know any distinction between a *full implementation* of a class from an *incomplete* one.
You can change class `first`, above, by adding a method that has no implementation:

```
struct first{
    std::string get_type() const {
        return "first";
    }
    void use_a_second(second const & second) const;
    void unused();
};
```

and the program will compile, link and run just the same. Since the
compiler emits no definition of `void first::unused()`, and since
the program does not attempt to invoke `void first::unused()` on
any object of type `first`, or to use its address, no mention of 
`void first::unused()` appears in the linkage at all. If
we change `main.cpp` to:

```
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"

int main()
{
    first f;
    second s;
    f.use_a_second(s);
    s.use_a_first(f);
    f.unused();
    return 0;
}
```

Then the linker will find a call to `void first::unused()` in `main.o`
and of course give an unresolved reference error. But this just
means that the linkage fails to provide an *implementation* that the
program needs. It doesn't mean that the *class definition* of
`first` is incomplete. If it was, compilation of `main.cpp` would have
failed, and no linkage would have been attempted.

Takeway:-

- Forward class declaration can avert compiletime deadlock of
  mutually dependent class definitions, with consequential refactoring.
- A forward class declaration can't avert an unresolved reference linkage
  error. Such an error always means that the implementation of
  a code symbol, or the value of a data symbol, is needed by the program
  and not provided by the linkage. A class declaration cannot add either
  one of those things to the linkage. It adds nothing to the linkage. It
  just directs the compiler to tolerate `foo` in contexts
  where where it is necessary and sufficient for `foo` to be a class-name.
- Linkage cannot provide any part of a class definition at linktime
  if, after a forward class declaration, the class definition becomes
  required, because a complete class definition will be required at compiletime or
  not at all. Linkage cannot provide parts of a class definition at all;
  only elements of the class *implementation*.

---

[1] To be clear:

```
class foo;
foo & bar();
...
foo * pfoo;
...
foo & rfoo = bar();
```

can compile, with merely the declaration of `class foo`, because neither
`foo * pfoo` or `foo & rfoo` requires an object of type `foo` to exist:
a pointer-to-foo, or reference-to-foo, is not a `foo`,

But:

```
class foo;
...
foo f; // Error
...
foo * pfoo; 
...
pfoo->method(); // Error
```

can't compile, because `f` must be a `foo`, and *the object addressed by* `pfoo`
must exist, and therefore be a `foo`, if any method is invoked through that
object.